# Sunspot Rails - Can user change what fields to search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails

I started using Sunspot to perform searches in my Rails 3 app and I ran into a doubt. Is there a way that I can let the user choose in what fields he/she wants to search. For example, in my app we have:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchable do
      text :name, :content, :keyword
    end
end
```

And in the View the default search bar:

```
<%= form_tag projects_path, :method => :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Can I add a radio button or something like that so the user can mark it in order just to search by name, or content or keyword? If yes, how can I make it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have no time for a proper explanation, but I believe you can pass a block to the search method, and provide options. Append an `if` clause to leave out certain options. In advanced cases, you might want to create more than one index.

Answer (score 1):

Watch the railscasts on the subject: http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot .. in it, Ryan lets user's query optionally by month.

So, if month was sent in:

```
def index
  @search = Article.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
    with(:publish_month, params[:month]) if params[:month].present?
  end
  @articles = @search.results
end
```